# Probability problem for at least two events?

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that the probability that you find a typo on a given page in any book is approximately $0.0025$. Find an approximation for the probability that in then next $1000$ pages that you read, you will find at least $2$ typos.

I have tried to do 
$1-P(\text{none}) = 1 - (0.9975)^{1000}$

but this is apparently wrong.

Comment: You calculated the probability that in the next $1000$ pages you find at least $1$ typo. They ask for at least $2$ typos.

Comment: Yes.  $1-P($none$) = P($at least $1)$, not $P($at least $2)$

Comment: how would i calculate that? would I subtract 1-(1-.9975^1000)?

Answer (score 2):

$1 - P(0)$ means "at least $1$ typo". So you have to find $1 - P(0) - P(1)$. You have $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ can be found as "this page contains $1$ typo, the other pages do not contain any typos * number of all possible permutations", so $P(1) = 0.0025 * (0.9975)^{999} * \binom{1000}{1} = 2.5 * (0.9975)^{999}$.